# Add additional columns to a very large MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I have a production server running MySQL (Engine=InnoDB). The database contains a large table of about 2GB size.

The table contains 20+ columns and 300k+ rows. Each cell contains large portions of text (articles, book chapters, ....).

The table contains about 20+ FULLTEXT KEY, so that the full content is indexed and the query for searching information very fast :)

Now, I need to add additional columns to the table.

If I run the query

```
alter table myTable
ADD COLUMN Column24 TEXT,
ADD COLUMN Column25 TEXT,
ADD COLUMN Column26 TEXT,
...
AFTER lastColumn;
```

MySQL reply, after about 3 hours with the message: "Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction". The table does not update.

I suspect the main problem is due to the Index. When MySQL rebuild the table, generates run-time the new full-text index that slow down dramatically the table update.

Is there a way to disable all FULLTEXT KEY, add the columns to the table very fast and then in background make MySQL rebuild all the indexes ?

The server is used by users and I do not want to make it offline during the process.

How can this problem be solved ?

Comment: You can't "disable" indexes. Instead you can drop these indexes, add columns and then recreate indexes

Comment: thanks for the answer Nikolai. How can I do this ? Will the server remains available for users ?

Comment: I'd recommend you to create one more table with these additional columns and reference it to your table 1:1 (by fact this will be 1:0/1) by primary key. This is very fast operation..

Comment: *Is there a way to disable all FULLTEXT KEY, add the columns to the table very fast and then in background make MySQL rebuild all the indexes ?* No, only drop indices then alter table then recreate indices.

Comment: Thank you Akina. "create one more table with these additional columns and reference it to your table 1:1 (by fact this will be 1:0/1) by primary key" Can you please explain how to do it ? is there a tutorial ?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/kYgeK1wd

Comment: Why don't you use an online schema change tool? At my last job, we used [pt-online-schema-change](https://docs.percona.com/percona-toolkit/pt-online-schema-change.html) and ran thousands of alters in production without interrupting service (on tables much larger than yours). As with any new tool, I suggest you try it in a safe environment until you're confident with it before trying it in production.